# External JavaScript file issues

Tags: javascript, html

Now this is just for reference for a future project but I am trying to call a function that reads in a string but displays a float after. So I first check the string then display a random number. The problem I am having, I think, is with the document.getElementById part. Any suggestions??

HTML File:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="letter" value=""/><br/>
        <input type="button" value="LETS DO THIS!" onclick="floatNum();"/></br>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="letNum.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

External JS File:

```
function floatNum()
{
    var val1 = document.getElementById("letter");

    if (isNaN(val1)
    {
        alert(Math.random())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code is working:-
    in your code,you missed  closing parenthesis ")" near to "if condition"

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>demo</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function floatNum()
            {
                var letter = document.getElementById("letter");

                if (isNaN(letter.value))// using input fields value not the whole object
                {
                    alert(Math.random());
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="letter" value="" /><br />
        <input type="button" value="LETS DO THIS!" onclick="floatNum();" />

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you want to pass in the element in the function, like so:

```
<input type="button" value="LETS DO THIS!" onclick="floatNum(document.getElementById('letter'))"/></br>
```

And in your JS

```
function floatNum(el)
{
    if (isNaN(el)
    {
        alert(Math.random())
    }
}
```

In case of a reusable function - try not to make it dependent on your DOM. Think about what would happen if you rename your element or want to use this function again. You couldn't before - now you can.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on this line:

```
var val1 = document.getElementById("letter");
```

It should be:

```
var val1 = document.getElementById("letter").value;
```

The first sets `val1` to the DOM element representing the input tag, the second sets it to the text value of the input tag (its contents).

Answer (score 0):

You need to process the **value** of input field not the input field itself.

```
function floatNum()
{
    var letter = document.getElementById("letter");

    if (isNaN(letter.value) // using input fields value not the whole object
    {
        alert(Math.random())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't grab the value of the input, but the input itself.

Correct code would be :

```
var val1 = document.getElementById("letter").value;
```